# Sort items of list by field of another table LINQ ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

So, I have my `Products` table in SSMS with these properties:

```
public class Product
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and my `Reports` table:

```
public class Report
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public ReportType ReportType { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return a `List<Product>` to my View that is sorted based on how many reports each `Product` has, but I can't figure out how to do it with LINQ. Any help/tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you declare DbContext ?

Answer (score 1):

If you put nav props in this would be:

```
context.Products.Include(p => p.Reports).OrderBy(p => p.Reports.Count(*));
```

But as you have no nav props, perhaps something like:

```
context.Products.OrderBy(p => context.Reports.Count(r => r.ProductId == p.Id));
```

The query ends up looking like this for the latter:

```
SELECT *
FROM p
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r WHERE p.id = r.id)
```

and similar but with a left join, for the former

---

You could also do it on the client side

```
var dict = context.Reports.GroupBy(r => ProductId, (k,g) => new { ProductId, Count = g.Count() } )
  .ToDictionary(at => at.ProductId, at => at.Count);
```

Then:

```
//or OrderByDescending if you want most reported products
var ret = context.Products.ToList().OrderBy(p => dict[p.ProductId]);
```

---

If you have some limited list of products:

```
var prods = context.Products.Where(...).ToList();
var prodIds = prods.Select(p => p.ProductId).ToArray();

var dict = context.Reports
  .Where(r => prods.Contains(r.ProductId))
  .GroupBy(r => ProductId, (k,g) => new { ProductId, Count = g.Count() } )
  .ToDictionary(at => at.ProductId, at => at.Count)

var ret = prods.OrderBy(p => dict[p.ProductId]);
```